# spring social linkedin. How do I know if linkedin user is/has a company?

Tags: spring, linkedin-api, spring-social, spring-social-linkedin

Is there a way to know if the logged in user (through linkedin) is/has a company associated ?

I need to allow access to my app only linkedin companies. How can I validate if the logged in user is a linkedin company or a regular user ?

Answer (score 0):

The `LinkedInProfile` class only contains the basic profile information which does not help in distinguishing if the logged in user is a regular user or company. This class extends `LinkedInObject` which contains `extraData` property for carrying any data in response from LinkedIn that won't be otherwise mapped to any properties of the subclass.

The `getExtraData` method returns a `Map<String, Object>` which contains the extra information. In this Map check if `company-type` key is available, if YES then you can conclude that the logged in user is of type Company.

The possible values of `company-type` are:

- C ("Public Company")
- D ("Educational")
- E ("Self Employed")
- G ("Government Agency")
- N ("Non Profit")
- O ("Self Owned")
- P ("Privately Held")
- S ("Partnership")

Comment: I had noticed the extraData() map but it is always empty. Is there an oauth scope I need to send to get those fields populated ?

Comment: ((LinkedIn) connection.getApi()).profileOperations().getUserProfile().getExtraData()

All info for userProfile is there, but not the extraData. Nothing special about the config. Just added   apply(new SpringSocialConfigurer()); toHttpSecurity

Comment: Instead of `((LinkedIn) connection.getApi()).profileOperations()` use `((LinkedIn) connection.getApi()).companyOperations()` for all company related queries.

Comment: all operations inside companyOperations() required an input such as company id, website, etc. Those are the fields that I don't have actually.
I need a way of knowing if the profile has/is a company.

Comment: Since you have the logged in user, you could use the ID and invoke the `getCompany(int id)` method. If the response is not null, you could be sure that the logged in user is of type company.

Comment: What I have is the user id (which is a string), I don't have the company id (which is an int). 
companyOperations() is just a class for company related operations but not attached to the logged in user, but any company.